# How to round to nearest hour using JavaScript Date Object

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project that requires a time in the future to be set using the Date object.

For example:

```
futureTime = new Date();
futureTime.setHours(futureTime.getHours()+2);
```

My questions is; once the future date is set, how can I round to the closest full hour and then set the futureTime var with it?

For example:

```
Given 8:55 => var futureTime = 9:00
Given 16:23 => var futureTime = 16:00
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Round the minutes and then clear the minutes:

```
var date = new Date(2011,1,1,4,55); // 4:55
roundMinutes(date); // 5:00

function roundMinutes(date) {

    date.setHours(date.getHours() + Math.round(date.getMinutes()/60));
    date.setMinutes(0, 0, 0); // Resets also seconds and milliseconds

    return date;
}
```

Comment: This might be incorrect depending on what you expect. E.g. if the time is 4:55:23.100 (or 4:55 and 23 seconds, 100 milliseconds) then this function will set the time to 5:00:23.100 (or 5:00 and 23 seconds and 100 milliseconds).

Comment: This is incorrect not only because of what @Felix has written, but also because you don't use Date UTC functions which may lead to buggy behaviour during the change of time to summer time and back (result will be different in different browsers).

Comment: @ivoszz you are more than welcome to edit the answer. The OP didn't ask about seconds or milliseconds. Also I don't understand your concerns with UTC time. Improve it if possible. Thanks

Comment: To fix the exact rounding as Felix Livni mentioned, you can use date.setMinutes(0,0,0), which also resets seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: As per @ivoszz comment, this is not the proper way to do date arithmetic in javascript. E.g. If your time is *Sun Mar 10 2019 01:30:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)* and then you round you should get *Sun Mar 10 2019 03:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)* due to the time zone change. And indeed this is the behavior in the latest Chrome browser, but it is not the case in the latest Safari browser (v12.1.1). In Safari you see the time as *Sun Mar 10 2019 02:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)* which is not a valid time.

Comment: @peter.bartos This should be THE answer!  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 35):

**<s>The other answers ignore seconds and milliseconds components of the date.</s>**

The accepted answer has been updated to handle milliseconds, but it still does not handle daylight savings time properly.

I would do something like this:

```
function roundToHour(date) {
  p = 60 * 60 * 1000; // milliseconds in an hour
  return new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / p ) * p);
}

var date = new Date(2011,1,1,4,55); // 4:55
roundToHour(date); // 5:00

date = new Date(2011,1,1,4,25); // 4:25
roundToHour(date); // 4:00
```

Comment: i agree, i also just find it easier to work with time in milliseconds (numbers), everything then just becomes basic math

Comment: +1 for sticking to millisecond math. However it's worth noting that the use of  `Math.ceil` is going to always round up and not give you _nearest hour_ as specified in the question.

Comment: Thanks @MarkEdington! I have updated the code to round to the nearest hour rather than to round up.

Comment: If you would extend this to days, and input date would be `Thu Apr 12 2018 13:48:56 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)`, the output would be `Thu Apr 12 2018 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)` which is not desired. It takes timezone and messes with it.

Comment: @Wish, I do not understand your comment. What do you mean by "extend this to days"?

Comment: @FelixLivni By "extend this to days" I guess he means roundToDay().
Great answer by the way and thank God that timezone only messes with hour and above.

Comment: @LinJian, you'd think so... but sadly no. Time zones can differ by 30-minutes, 15-minutes, 45-minutes, e.g. Kathmandu is GMT +5:45. There are also some strange cases like Samoa which is on the international date line and has jumped forward (and also backwards another time) an entire 24-hours skipping and introducing an entire day: In 2011 Samoa went from Dec 29 straight to Dec 31!

Comment: I have written this, in ts: `function roundDate(date: Date, stepMillis: number, round: 'floor' | 'round' | 'ceil') {
  return new Date(Math[round](date.getTime() / stepMillis ) * stepMillis);
}` It allows like, rounding to 5, 15, 30mins or any other time step you want

Answer (score 23):

A slightly simpler way :

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes (d.getMinutes() + 30);
d.setMinutes (0);
```

Comment: I like this, it's simple and it also will change the date object instead of simply returning a representation.

Comment: Note: This might be incorrect depending on what you expect. E.g. if the time is 4:55:23.100 (or 4:55 and 23 seconds, 100 milliseconds) then this function will set the time to 5:00:23.100 (or 5:00 and 23 seconds and 100 milliseconds)

Comment: To fix the exact rounding as Felix Livni mentioned, you can use d.setMinutes(0,0,0), which also resets seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: @peter.bartos Sorry, I think you're quoting someone else. I believe d.setMinutes(0,0,0) does not work at DST boundaries. See my response in the comments of the accepted answer for an example.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, which is no where near as graceful as IAbstractDownvoteFactory's

```
var d = new Date();
if(d.getMinutes() >= 30) {
   d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1);
}
d.setMinutes(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could mix the two for optimal size. 
http://jsfiddle.net/HkEZ7/

```
function roundMinutes(date) {
    return date.getMinutes() >= 30 ? date.getHours() + 1 : date.getHours();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact Javascript does this default which gives wrong time.

```
let dateutc="2022-02-17T07:20:00.000Z";
let bd = new Date(dateutc);
console.log(bd.getHours()); // gives me 8!!!!!
```

it is even wrong for my local time because I am GMT+2 so it should say 9.
`moment.js` also does it wrong so you need to be VERY carefull

Answer (score -1):

Pass any cycle you want in milliseconds to get next cycle example 1 hours

```js
function calculateNextCycle(interval) {
    const timeStampCurrentOrOldDate = Date.now();
    const timeStampStartOfDay = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    const timeDiff = timeStampCurrentOrOldDate - timeStampStartOfDay;
    const mod = Math.ceil(timeDiff / interval);
    return new Date(timeStampStartOfDay + (mod * interval));
}

console.log(calculateNextCycle(1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // 1 hours in milliseconds
```