# How to convert ISO string format date time to next hour

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I am using the following function to convert my date in RFC3339. I want it to convert in upper limit.

Can anyone assist me, how do I convert it to upper limit?

```
 const date = new Date();
    // RFC 3339 format
    const targetTime = date.toISOString();
```

**Current output is:**

```
2022-12-20T05:26:12.968Z
```

**Expected output should be**

```
2022-12-20T06:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7293327/1524592), very similar but you can replace `Math.round` with `Math.ceil` to round up like you want and in addition you'll need to get the percentage the hour is complete (assuming you don't want to round up exact hours).

```
const milliSecondsInHour = 60*60*1000;
const roundDateToNextHour = (date: Date) => {
    const percentHourComplete = (x.getTime() % milliSecondsInHour) / milliSecondsInHour;
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + Math.ceil(percentHourComplete));
    date.setMinutes(0, 0, 0); // Resets also seconds and milliseconds
    return date;
}
```

Comment: @RobG - thank you! Updated my answer for correctness to handle that case

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to the next full UTC hour, test if UTC minutes, seconds or milliseconds are greater than zero. If any of them are, increment the hour and zero the other values, e.g.:

```js
// If the provided date is not exactly on the UTC hour, 
// return a date that is the next full UTC hour after
// the provided date.
function toFullUTCHour(date) {
  let d = new Date(+date);
  d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() + (d.getUTCMinutes() || d.getUTCSeconds() || d.getUTCMilliseconds? 1 : 0), 0,0,0);
  return d;
}

let d = new Date()
console.log(d.toISOString() + '\n' +
  toFullUTCHour(d).toISOString());
 
// Simplified version, only works in general for UTC hour
function ceilUTCHour(date = new Date()) {
  let d = new Date(+date);
  d.setHours(d.getHours() + (d%3.6e6? 1 : 0), 0, 0, 0);
  return d;
}

console.log(ceilUTCHour(d).toISOString());
```

Since, in ECMAScript, UTC days are always exactly 8.64e7 ms long and hours are always exactly 3.6e6 ms long, you can just get the remainder of the current UTC time value and if it's not zero (which will be almost always) add 1 to the UTC hour, then zero the minutes seconds and milliseconds as for the *ceilUTCHour* function above.